# What does <<-CONSTANT do?

Tags: ruby, syntax, heredoc

```
return <<-HTML
  <li>
    <a href = "some-link">Link-Title</a>
  </li>
HTML
```

What are <<-HTML on the first line and HTML on the last line for?

Comment: @jleedev: Is it ok to have the answer as a tag? :)

Comment: For “what is this syntax” types of questions, I feel that adding the tag makes the Internet better.

Comment: @jleedev: It allows people to use this question to go the other way-- that is, if you hear the term "heredoc" and you want to know what it is, you could search for the tags [ruby] [heredoc] and get this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a heredoc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby

Answer (score 2):

That's a here document. Basically, it's a multi-line string literal.

On lines after the line with the `<<-HTML`, those are literal strings concatenated by newlines-- until the end marker is reached, which in this case is `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly answer the question, this snippet returns the string:

<li>

```
<a href = "some-link">Link-Title</a>
```

</li>