# Can someone explain this ruby code?

Tags: ruby, syntax, heredoc

From the rails [postgresql_adapter.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75dc9fbac76a2da78b8d21e1ede16fea38d16564/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb).  I get what it's trying to do, I just don't get how it happens.  It's really to do with the <<-SQL that I'm lost.

```
exec_query(<<-SQL, 'SCHEMA', binds).rows.first[0].to_i > 0
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM pg_tables
  WHERE tablename = $1
  #{schema ? "AND schemaname = $2" : ''}
SQL
```

I've seen code before where you could say:

```
blah = <<-X
 some
 lines
 of
 test
X
```

But I've never seen this done within the argument to a function call.  I'm really confused by this.  Can someone explain to me what exactly is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this Ruby snippet do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608902/what-does-this-ruby-snippet-do)

Comment: nope, i understand the snippet part as mentioned...  but I didn't know you could use it within a function argument

Comment: Ah, so you did. On re-reading, I'm not particularly surprised at being able to do a heredoc as an argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a heredoc-marker (like `<<-SQL` in your example) anywhere (or even multiple times) in a line and the heredoc will then start on the following line and continue until the end-marker is met (in case of multiple markers, the (n+1)th heredoc will start after the nth end-marker and continue up to the (n+1)th end-marker). The content of each heredoc will then be inserted at the place where the corresponding marker was used.

So

```
foo(<<BAR, 42)
bar
BAR
```

is the same as

```
foo("bar\n", 42)
```

and

```
foo(<<BAR, <<BAZ)
bar
BAR
baz
BAZ
```

is the same as

```
foo("bar\n", "baz\n")
```

Comment: that's so odd!  I don't understand why you would do this at all.  why not just assign your string to a variable then use that in the function?

Comment: @brad: I wouldn't, but I suppose the possibility is there because it's somewhat more concise (ruby can be quite perlish sometimes).