# What are <-- Ruby Strings called? And how do I insert variables in them?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

`<--` Seems to be unsearchable on the web so had to ask the question here.

What is their searchable name, and how do I add variables inline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this Ruby snippet do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608902/what-does-this-ruby-snippet-do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That syntax is for declaring a HERE DOCUMENT 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc

> There's a line-oriented form of the string literals that is usually
>   called as `here document'. Following a << you can specify a string or
>   an identifier to terminate the string literal, and all lines following
>   the current line up to the terminator are the value of the string. If
>   the terminator is quoted, the type of quotes determines the type of
>   the line-oriented string literal. Notice there must be no space
>   between << and the terminator.
>
> If the - placed before the delimiter, then all leading whitespcae
>   characters (tabs or spaces) are stripped from input lines and the line
>   containing delimiter. This allows here-documents within scripts to be
>   indented in a natural fashion.

Regarding interpolation, the link gives more details, but it is like a double quoted string if your string is delimited as below (ignore this page's color formatting)

```
<<-HERE
   I can interpolate #{foo}
HERE
```

whereas it is like a single quoted string

```
<<-'HERE'
 This will print out #{foo} as text
HERE
```

Also the original pickaxe is a good source  http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html

Answer (score 2):

`<<-FOO` is a here document. You can [read more about them here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

And regular interpolation works in here docs as well.

```
str = <<-STR
  #{foo}
STR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<<HEREDOC
This is like a double quoted string
Interpolation happens here. #{1+2}
Backslashes are interpreted as escapes. \a\t
HEREDOC
```

http://jeff.dallien.net/posts/optional-behavior-for-ruby-heredocs